# Prove that $f(x)=5x^3+9$ has inverse in all $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I have to prove that the function $f(x)=5x^3+9$ has inverse in all $\mathbb{R}$ (I know that graphically it is trivial).

Is it enough to consider that it is strictly monotonic? Is it necessary to prove that it is also continuous?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can show it's a bijection, since all bijections have inverses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

- $f(x)=5x^3+9 \implies f'(x)=15x^2\ge 0 \quad f(x)=0 \iff x=0$

and

- $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)=\pm \infty$

what can we conclude about injectivity and surjectivity from here for $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If the derivative is *only* positive everywhere in its domain, then is monotonic, thus it is injective, right?

Then, as the derivative can be calculated in all its domain, the function is continuous, and goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, so logically it covers all $\mathbb{R}$, so it is surjective.

We have proved that the function is bijective, so it is invertible on its range ($\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @P4U Yes exactly, for the continuity it suffices just to observe that $f(x)$ is a polynomial function defined and continuos $\forall x$. Note that in general $f'(x)\ge 0$ implies that $f(x)$ is increasing but since $f'(x)=0$ not on an interval we have that it $f(x)$ strictly increasind and thus injective.

Comment: Alright, I have understood it perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: @P4U Well done! You are welcome, Bye

Answer (score 3):

Continuity has nothing to do with having an inverse. What you want to show is that your function is bijective. That is, $f$ is one-to-one and onto. Also, you could exchange $x$ and $y$ in your function and then solve for $y$ (or just solve for $y$ in terms of $x$).

## Edit

It isn't completely true that continuity as nothing to do with having an inverse. While it is not at all necessarily that a continuous function be invertible or invertible function be continuous, in the case where $f$ is continuous and monotonic it is indeed invertible on its range.

Comment: I think that OP wanted to make use of the fact that a continuous function is invertible on its range if and only if it is strictly monotonic, so continuity has something to do with the inverse in this sense.

Comment: Yeah, fair point. I should have been more specific.

Comment: Note that $f(x)=e^x$ is monotonic and continuous but it is not invertible as $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, as we know indeed it is only invertible as $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: @gimusi Note that I wrote "invertible *on its range*"

Comment: @Sobi That's nice, I was referring to the edit for that answer which seems to not point out that.

Comment: @gimusi Oh, I see!

Comment: There isn't a need to be rude friend. I wasn't specific enough because of the comment but I edited and it has been fixed. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @RhythmInk No rudeness here! Not between me and Sobi and neither with you from my side! Now it's fine, Bye.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to prove that the inverse is continuous indeed there are noncontinuous functions with noncontinuous inverses. Note however that a continuous function if it has an inverse must have a continuous inverse. Write $y = 5x^3+9$ and try to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. HINT: $x^{3}$ has the inverse $x^{1/3}$

You can also use that $f$ is strictly monotonic. Can you show this?